# Mime type and PATHINFO_EXTENSION

Tags: php, mime-types

I am using [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to find the extension of a file type.

```
pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
```

Looking at the PHP manual, it doesn't clarify *how* this function gets this information. Does this check the image for its MIME type and return that or does it just find the extension by using `explode()` or such?

If the MIME is not returned, what is the most 'modern' way of checking a files MIME type?

And is it a wise to compare the MIME with the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [finfo_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) and `finfo_open` to check MIME of files.

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

> text/html